# Seating in Soyuz 18 capsule

Tags: soyuz-spacecraft

Working on an alternate-history SF story that involves an orbital rescue in 1975 requiring use of the Soyuz 18 capsule.  This had room for carrying up to 3 cosmonauts to orbit but only carried 2 to the Soviet Salyut 4 station in 1975. If they tried to return to Earth in it with 3 people instead of 2, would that have been possible?  I assume they didn't launch from Earth with an empty 3rd seat; why waste the mass?  But would there have been room for a 3rd person on return, assuming they cobble together some kind of cushion/seat?  Anyone know how the actual interior of Soyuz 18 was configured?  Thanks all.

Comment: Related, not a duplicate: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12926/6944

Comment: I clearly remember Shenzhou 11 launched with an empty seat (with cargo strapped to it) http://english.cas.cn/newsroom/news/201610/t20161019_168764.shtml.

Comment: It's plausible, but in any case why let facts get in the way of a good scifi story?

Answer (score 3):

**No.**  At least, not easily.  Soyuz 18 used a variant of the Soyuz capsule (the [7K-ST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_7K-T)) that could only handle two crew.  After Soyuz 11 tragedy, the spacecraft was redesigned so that the space that would be taken up by another crew member was instead taken up by life support.  So there would be a major redesign of the spacecraft required in order to do that (which happened when the [Soyuz-T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz-T) was designed).

Comment: After Soyuz 18 left Salyut 4, apparently an uncrewed Soyuz 20, with 'biological samples' was sent up to Salyut 4 for a few months.  Anyone have knowledge of how  its interior was laid out (any seats?).  Or what the 'samples' were?  Did it have a conventional reentry, IOW would g-forces be same as a crewed capsule?  Thanks for any input.