# Evacuating the ISS but wait, there's only one Spacecraft?

Tags: spacex, iss, soyuz-spacecraft, dragon-v2, roscosmos

I was doing some research regarding the Soyuz as I'm currently planning a summer project in which I would build a close replica of a Soyuz when the question popped into my mind, "What would happen if there was a freak accident in which that the ISS needed to be evacuated and there was ONLY one space craft available?" I'll leave y'all's response on the matter to either be regarding the Crew Dragon or the Soyuz.

Comment: somewhat related: [How often are fewer than three astronauts present when moving a Soyuz spacecraft from one docking port to another?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50908/12102) and [Why have astronauts had to take Soyuz capsules “out for a spin” on 15 separate occasions? (move from one Soyuz port to another)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50716/12102)

Comment: Tether the extra astronauts to one of the departing vehicles. Keep the vehicle in orbit until a rescue vehicle arrives. Then, move them into the rescue vehicle and bring them all back to earth. No? :D

Comment: @user39728 if there were enough EVA suits (there aren't) and if they were fast to put  on (they aren't) and if you could get to the airlock (scenario dependent) and if they had long enough endurance (~1 day, not enough), this would be a great idea. But, no.

Comment: Got it, need quick suits, more suits, and an oxygen line with universal adapters to plug to any visiting space vehicle as last recourse : D

Comment: "Go to rockets full." / Not responding /"Hello Major Tom /Are you receiving? /Turn the thrusters on /We're standing by." /There's no reply

Answer (score 58, accepted):

By design that will never happen. There are always enough return seats for the crew.

This is exactly why

- the whole crew of one of the visiting vehicles gets in it whenever it undocks, even when it is only being moved from one docking port of the station to another
- the crews retreat to their vehicles in fire / leak / toxic atmosphere emergencies
- the crews retreat to their vehicles if a collision risk is discovered too late to execute a safe distancing maneuver

See also [Can a single Soyuz return a crew of six back to Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12926/6944)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123137/discussion-on-answer-by-organic-marble-evacuating-the-iss-but-wait-theres-only).

Answer (score 28):

> What would happen if there was a freak accident in which that the ISS needed to be evacuated and there was ONLY one space craft available?

Carrying that to an even greater extreme, what would happen if there was a freak accident in which the ISS needed to be evacuated and no space craft was available? For example, suppose two human-qualified vehicles are docked with the ISS. Suppose an unseen 10 cm diameter asteroid hits one of those escape vehicles at 30 km/s. It would rip right through that vehicle. Suppose it ripped open a propellant tank. Kaboom! Suppose some of the resulting debris opened holes in the ISS, and other chunks opened holes in the other escape vehicle.

The answer is simple: The astronauts and cosmonauts on the ISS will die. Being an astronaut, cosmonaut, or taikonaut is not exactly the safest career choice. One of the standard questions potential astronauts are asked is whether they are willing to die given that over 10% of astronauts have died on the job. Potential astronauts have to be willing to accept that possible outcome. They also have to be not willing to desire that possible outcome.

The ISS is intended to be two fault tolerant regarding loss of life at the three sigma level with respect to reasonably plausible failures. The ISS is not even one fault tolerant with respect to some outrageously implausible root causes such as my hypothetical 10 cm asteroid. It's also noteworthy that the three sigma level is not that high of a bar; modern Earth-bound manufacturing is moving toward making the devices they make safe and reliable at the six sigma level.

Bottom line: There are semi-plausible scenarios where astronauts or cosmonauts will die. This is a risk that astronauts and cosmonauts sign on for, but it also is a risk that they work very aggressively to counteract.

Comment: Either you die, or you beat Felix Baumgartner's record ;-).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica You'd need the delta-v to de-orbit, first. Might work if last they ate was cabbage soup.

Comment: @Polygnome A job for Jo Nesbo's [Doctor Proctor](https://www.amazon.com/Doctor-Proctors-Powder-Doktor-Proktor-ebook/dp/B0030H7UAS)! :-)

Comment: Do you have a source for that 10% statistic? I know there's already a [follow-up](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/51428/time-trends-in-astronaut-fatality-rates) question but anyway.

Comment: @EverydayAstronaut My sources are personal. I've been fortunate to know three fantastic people who progressed fairly highly in the very competitive astronaut candidate selection process. While none made it to the stage of being an ASCAN (astronaut candidate), they did progress far enough so as to have been subjected to various forms of what I would call torture. Some of the torture was physical (e.g., being centrifuged), but most was psychological.

Comment: Asking "are you willing to die" is a form of psychological torture, particularly when backed up with probabilities close to those of Russian roulette. Whether that number is valid is a different question. All three of those candidate astronauts (as opposed to astronaut candidates) told me about being asked such a question by NASA.

Comment: 10% only because of one vehicle that was unsafe at any speed.  One day they'll find the Intrepid sunk at its moorings (despite resting on silt), and when they investigate, the root cause will trace back to the Space Shuttle somehow lol...

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica 355 individuals flew on the shuttle and 14 got killed by it. Admittedly my math isn't great but that's about 4%  Not sure folks getting killed in the space program is the best thing to 'lol' about

Comment: @OrganicMarble Astronauts have also died in training exercises (e.g., Apollo 1), in  training flights / experimental flights (e.g., various T-38 and experimental aircraft accidents), and even in required commercial travel.  It's a good deal more than 14 deaths. In addition, your 355 number is high. This is a per career statistic rather than a per flight statistic. The two astronauts who flew on the Shuttle seven times only count as two instead of fourteen. There were a lot of astronauts who flew the Shuttle more than once.

Comment: @DavidHammen my 355 number is exact. I said 355 "individuals" flew on the shuttle, and that is correct. https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/566250main_2011.07.05%20SHUTTLE%20ERA%20FACTS.pdf  There are many ways to slice and dice the numbers depending on what your desired result is.

Comment: @OrganicMarble you lifted my "lol" out of context, so no "high horse" for you...

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica cool, now work on your 10%

Comment: @DavidHammen Your answer says "given that over 10% of astronauts have died on the job" which I find misleading ... given that your comment says "Whether that number is valid is a different question". Anyway thanks for the interesting story about those 3 people's experiences.

Answer (score 6):

There WAS a different concept for returning folks from orbit in emergencies that was considered, called [MOOSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOOSE), but it never got out of the planning stages.

[image: MOOSE]